# sqlalchemy relationship primaryjoin with self and parent columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I have models:

```
class A(Base):
    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    other = Column(Text)
    name = Column(Text)


class B(Base):
    b_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    other = Column(Text)


class C(Base):
    c_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(ForeignKey(B.b_id))
    b = relationship(B)
    name = Column(Text)

    a = relationship(
        A,
        primaryjoin=and_(
            A.name == foreign(name),
            A.other == foreign(B.other)))
```

How can I get the relationship `C.a` to work such that `session.query(C).options(joinedload(C.a))` doesn't fail.

In plain SQL I would do:

```
select * from c 
join b using(b_id) 
join a on a.name = c.name and a.other = b.other
```

There is a unique constraint on `a.name, a.other`, so I know I will get either 1 or 0 `a`s per `c`.

I imagine I need to be using `secondary=` in some way, but all the examples I can find are pure many-to-many examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, could you flesh out what you're after in plain SQL?

Comment: Oh and is that supposed to be a many-to-one relationship, or...? It's also a bit confusing that the primary join does not use `C.b_id`.

Comment: sorry @IljaEverilä for not providing too much detail, in plain SQL I would do: 
`select * from c join b using(b_id) join a on a.name = c.name and a.other = b.other`. There is a unique constraint on `a.name, a.other`, so I know I will get either 1 or 0 `a`s per `c`.

Comment: Thank you for providing those details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a secondary you have to use a [relationship to a non primary mapper](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#relationship-to-non-primary-mapper), because:

> There is one complex join case where even this technique [(composite "secondary" join)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins) is not sufficient; when we seek to join from `A` to `B`, making use of any number of `C`, `D`, etc. in between, **however there are also join conditions between `A` and `B` *directly***. In this case, the join from `A` to `B` may be difficult to express with just a complex [`primaryjoin`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.primaryjoin) condition, as the intermediary tables may need special handling, and **it is also not expressable with a [`secondary`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.secondary) object**, since the `A->secondary->B` pattern does not support any references between `A` and `B` directly.

So following the example from the documentation we can build your relationship, using a [non primary mapper](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#multiple-mappers-for-one-class) that maps the class `A` against a join between the tables `a` and `b`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Text, ForeignKey, join, and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, mapper, sessionmaker, foreign
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = engine
Session = sessionmaker()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    other = Column(Text)
    name = Column(Text)


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    b_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    other = Column(Text)

j = join(A, B, A.other == B.other)
A_viab = mapper(A, j, non_primary=True, properties={
    "other": [j.c.a_other, j.c.b_other]
})


class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    c_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(ForeignKey(B.b_id))
    b = relationship(B)
    name = Column(Text)

    a = relationship(
        A_viab,
        primaryjoin=and_(foreign(name) == A_viab.c.name,
                         b_id == A_viab.c.b_id))
```

and in action:

```
In [4]: session.add(A(name='name', other='other'))

In [5]: session.add(C(name='name', b=B(other='other')))

In [6]: session.commit()
...

In [7]: c = session.query(C).options(joinedload(C.a)).first()
2018-01-04 15:10:21,338 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2018-01-04 15:10:21,340 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT c.c_id AS c_c_id, c.b_id AS c_b_id, c.name AS c_name, a_1.other AS a_1_other, b_1.other AS b_1_other, a_1.a_id AS a_1_a_id, a_1.name AS a_1_name, b_1.b_id AS b_1_b_id 
FROM c LEFT OUTER JOIN (a AS a_1 JOIN b AS b_1 ON a_1.other = b_1.other) ON c.name = a_1.name AND c.b_id = b_1.b_id
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
2018-01-04 15:10:21,340 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1, 0)

In [8]: c.a
Out[8]: <cplxjoin.A at 0x7f0c81599630>
```

The resulting query is not exactly identical to your manual SQL, but afaic should be equivalent.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Got a fair bit to mull over there, including the generated SQL itself, I wonder if I can force the query to be generated the (to me) more natural way round, will have a play.

Comment: The relationship supports populating as well btw: `session.add(C(b=B(other='bar'), a=A(other='bar', name='qwe')))` will handle setting `C.name` correctly. You only have to manually provide `B.other` and `A.other`. And if you prefer using INNER JOIN (no results for C without A), pass `innerjoin=True` to `joinedload()`, or [make it the default of the relationship attribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.innerjoin).

Comment: I also think that in order to make a LEFT JOIN, the joins generated by SQLAlchemy are good. The thing about eager loading is that it should not affect the original query – [The Zen of Joined Eager Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#the-zen-of-joined-eager-loading) is a good read.

Comment: Excellent advice, I have kept everything in my solution except, I made `properties={"other": [A.__table__.c.other, B.__table__.c.other]}` so that the intermediate variable `j` wasn't needed and everything could be contained in `C`. Thanks again!